# Add AddressSanitizer to the c++ dynamic library of the Android application using static linking

Tags: android, c++

I try to add the functionality of AddressSanitizer to my Android dynamic library according to the following [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/asan?hl=zh-cn). I have to integrate libclang_rt.asan-arm-android.so in my project. Can I use static linkage instead of dynamic linkage in Clang/LLVM tool chain

Answer (score 3):

You don't. Core OpenGL 3.2+ does not permit rendering without using a VAO. Just as it does not permit rendering without a shader.